# Why do identical strings return false with ==?

Tags: python, string

This is the simplified version of my problem.

```
QA = open('Qestions and answers.txt')
Q = []
A = []

for line in QA:
  (first,second) = line.split(';')
   Q.append(first)
   A.append(second)

QA.close()

print(A[0], A[1])
print(A[0] == '1981')
print(A[1] == 'Feb')
print(str(A[0]) == '1981') # I even tried str
print(str(A[1]) == "Feb")
```

Output:

```
1981
 Feb

False
False
False
False
```

Comment: There's probably some whitespace in there (or other characters you can't easily notice when you print the strings).

Comment: The answer is *"they don't"*. Your strings are unequal, try e.g. `print(repr(A[0]), repr('1981')` to see this clearly.

Comment: See how the output of `print(A[0], A[1])` stretches over _three_ lines? That's because there are two `\n` in it!

Comment: Your line has a line break at the end. Q will match because I doesn't have the line break, A doesn't because of the line break.

Comment: Also, FWIW it seems like questions and answers might more naturally be stored in a dictionary: `q_and_a = { q : a for q, a in line.strip().split(';') }`

Answer (score 4):

You've got extra whitespace in there.  My guess is this:

```
print(repr(A[0]))
```

Output:

```
'1981\n'
```

This is because when you read lines from a file, you will get the line breaks at the end of each line as well.  If you don't want that, strip them out.

```
for line in QA:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    ...
```

Comment: Or just `line.strip()`, it seems unlikely that any whitespace at either end is useful.

Comment: The whitespace is caused by the comma in `print(A[0], A[1])`. There is actually no whitespace in `A[1]`

Comment: @MoonCheesez How do you know there isn't trailing spaces or tabs? Are you at the OP's computer and have access to their input file?  It looks like there is a trailing newline for both words, for what it's worth.

Comment: @SethMMorton I am referring to Dietrich's "You've got extra whitespace in there" which refers to the question's "1981\n
 Feb\n". Not generally.

Comment: @MoonCheesez: "Whitespace" includes `\n`.  I was talking about the `\n`.  The space is not extra, it is expected.

Answer (score 0):

strip() works for this problem

```
print(A[0].strip() == '1981')
print(A[1].strip() == 'Feb')


True
True
```